# LinkedIn API request usage incorrect #linkedin #linkedin-api

Tags: linkedin-api

The account dashboard for our LinkedIn API app shows that two users are over their limits for the `socialActions/comments-GET_ALL` request. Each user has a 50,000 request limit per day. That seems like a lot so I checked the logs of our application which are very verbose for LinkedIn API requests and it shows that between the two of them, 517 requests are being sent each day. This is nowhere close to the 50,000 limit that is shown.

When being rate limited, `(429) Too Many Requests.` errors are being sent.

Are requests weighted for the LinkedIn API and maybe each single `socialActions/comments-GET_ALL` request counts as 20 requests? What else could be happening?

I looked at the documentation provided here for [LinkedIn Rate Limiting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/api-guide/concepts/rate-limits) but it sounds like 1 request counts as 1 request but I know for a fact that this isn't the case.

Comment: do you know if its possible to get the posts data from your home page via api ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking...

Comment: I meant the linkedin home page feed data, to extract the posts from our linkedin home page.

Comment: Could somebody from #linkedin please help with this?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, this definitely sounds pretty strange...

If you look at your developer analytics, how many requests do you see for that particular endpoint?

I have been building on LinkedIn's APIs for a while now and never encountered any rate limit - both in development & stress testing, and in production.

One thing I can say though is that their docs and return errors are pretty badly put together: one time I was getting a 500 Internal server error for a malformed request.

My best suggestion would be to just contact their support team through the [Zendesk support form](https://linkedin.zendesk.com/hc/en-us). They are pretty quick at replying usually :)